# How to use a Server key to access Google API?

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have registered my project on Google developers and have generated a server key, NOT an OAuth2.0 key. How do I use this server key to use the Google API. The exact API that I want to use is the YouTube Data API. I have found documentation for using the OAuth2.0 key, but not for the simple server key that I have. My project is in Python.

Comment: You can just directly use those server keys to access Google API especially for making simple HTTP requests and getting simple data access.

Answer (score 0):

Not every endpoint that is part of the YouTube API requires OAuth to make the request.  Take the [`commentThreads/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) endpoint.  This endpoint is used to get a thread of comments on a video.  This does not require OAuth, and only requires an API key.  Use the following parameters:

`part` -> `id,snippet`

`videoId` -> `jCHE0Tjw6MA` (or the video ID you want to return the comments for)

`key` -> Your server API key

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id%2Csnippet&videoId=jCHE0Tjw6MA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Comment: I tried calling the method with youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', key='my_key'), but it gives an error saying that key is an unexpected argument. When I replaced key with developerKey='my_key' I got an error saying "WARNING:root:No module named locked_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/__init__.py", line 38, in autodetect
    from . import file_cache
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/googleapiclient/discovery_cache/file_cache.py", line 32, in <module>
ImportError: No module named locked_file"